# Make ListView background image match TextView size - How to?

Tags: android, listview, background, textview

Considering there are other components beyond TextView on my ListView, I would like to know if there is a way (programmactically) to make my ListView background image match TextView (or any other component) size inside it or do I need to resize the image manually?

How I would like that looks:

[image: How I would like that looks]

How it looks:

[image: How it looks]

Comment: If you want it to be the same size as your textview, why are you setting the image as the background of your listview?

Comment: Because there are other components in the list view such as image and button

Comment: So you can't set it as the background for the textview, correct? Have you tried toying around with wrapping all your components which need the background in a layout and setting the background of that layout?

Comment: Still image getting larger than any component

Comment: Yeah, but you can set the height of that layout, which you don't want to do for your listview. Because you probably have somewhat of an idea of how big each item of a list is going to be (or you can set it programmatically, also an option). This might give some scaling issues though, but it will present an image with the correct size

Comment: Thank you, considering my background won't be affected by scale problems, setting  ``android:layout_height="60px"`` on ListView solved my problem, post as an answer please

Comment: Done. Glad to hear it helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried toying around with wrapping all your components which need the background in a layout and setting the background of that layout?

You can set the height of that layout, which you don't want to do for your listview. Because you probably have somewhat of an idea of how big each item of a list is going to be (or you can set it programmatically, also an option). This might give some scaling issues though, but it will present an image with the correct size.

For example:

```
<LinearLayout
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="60px" >

    <TextView
    ... />
    <ImageView
    ... />
</LinearLayout>
```